# Legend for bar chart with horizontal bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `ggplot2` to produce a bar chart and I would like to include my main result as well as a "gold standard" on the same chart. I have tried a couple of methods but I am not able to produce an appropriate legend for the chart.

## Method 1

Here I use `geom_col()` for my main result and `geom_errorbar()` for my "gold standard". I don't know how to show a simple legend (red = gold standard, blue = score) to match this chart. Additionally, I don't like that the error bar overlaps the axis grid line at 1.00 (instead of meeting it exactly).

```
chart_A_data <- data_frame(students= c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"),
                         score = c(0.5, 0.7, 0.8),
                         max_score = c(1, 1 , 1))

chart_A <- ggplot(chart_A_data, aes(x = students, y = score)) +
  geom_col(fill = "blue") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = max_score, ymax = max_score),
                size = 2, colour = "red") +
  ggtitle("Chart A", subtitle = "Use errorbars to show \"gold standard\"")
chart_A
```

[image: chart A]

## Method 2

Here I create dummy variables and produce a stacked bar chart using `geom_bar()` and then make the unused dummy variable transparent. I am happy with how precise this method is but I don't know how to remove the unused dummy variable from my legend. Additionally, In this case I need to treat any score of 1.00 as a special case (i.e. set it to 0.99 to make space for the "gold standard").

```
chart_B_data <- chart_A_data %>%
  select(-max_score) %>%
  # create dummy variables for stacked bars, note: error if score>0.99
  mutate(max_score_line = 0.01) %>%
  mutate(blank_fill = 0.99 - score) %>%
  gather(stat_level, pct, -students) %>%
  # set as factor to control order of stacked bars
  mutate(stat_level = factor(stat_level,
                             levels = c("max_score_line", "blank_fill", "score"),
                             labels = c("max", "", "score")))

chart_B <- ggplot(data = chart_B_data,
                  aes(x = students, y = pct, fill = stat_level, alpha = stat_level)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "pink", "blue")) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(1,0,1)) + 
  ggtitle("Chart B", subtitle = "Create dummy variables and use stacked bar chart")
chart_B
```

[image: Chart B]

I don't mind if there is a completely different way I should be approaching this, but I really would like to be able to show a gold standard on my bar chart with a simple concise legend. I will be writing a script to do 50-60 of these charts so I don't want to have too many "special cases" to think about.

Answer (score 0):

In case there's only one `max score`: This may seem a little hacky (and probably not that beautiful), but it does the job:

```
ggplot(chart_A_data, aes(x = students, y = score))+
    geom_col()+
    geom_hline(yintercept = chart_A_data$max_score)
```

Another one:

```
ggplot(chart_A_data, aes(x = students, 
                         y = score, 
                         fill = students))+
    geom_col()+
    geom_segment(aes(x = as.numeric(students)-.15, 
                     xend = as.numeric(students)+.15, 
                     y = max_score, 
                     yend = max_score, 
                     color = students))
```

Here for the case there are variable maximum scores for each student (you may need to play with the hard-coded `0.15` untill you find something suitable):

[image: plot]

### Edit after the OP clarified request:

```
ggplot(chart_A_data, aes(x = students, 
                         y = score))+
  geom_col(aes(fill = "blue"))+
  geom_segment(aes(x = as.numeric(students)-.25, 
                   xend = as.numeric(students)+.25, 
                   y = max_score, 
                   yend = max_score, color = "red"), 
                size = 1.7)+
  scale_fill_identity(name = "", 
                      guide = "legend", 
                      labels = "Score")+
  scale_color_manual(name = "", 
                     values = ("red" = "red"), 
                     labels = "Max Score")
```

Which produces:

[image: edited plot]

Comment: parameter `size` will give you a thicker / thinner line

Comment: my main issue is that I can get a legend that has just a red box or line for "max score" and a blue box for "student score"

Comment: @bmrn see my edit. If you consider the answer helpful, you may want to check the tick mark indicating it answered your question and upvote it.